# Group geometry points and create a linestring for each group

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, query, linestring

I have a table of points at a Postgres database that have two main columns **(geom geometry, time timestamp)**.

I need a query to retrieve as linestrings or as array of the geometries the points that are close to each other by 1 m aprox and follow the sequence of time.

The points table:

[image]

Example:

[image]

Within this set of points, how can i get in a query those two sequences of points as two different linestrings? Also excluding points that are isolated.

Assuming that this is a particular case within millions like those two cases, which would be the more efficient way to find all the linestrings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among the most versatile approaches would be to use `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` to create cluster of points based on distance; apart from the general uncertainty of results due to the lack of a common identifier, the only drawback is that it currently only supports the `GEOMETRY` type and is thus limited to the CRS units (*degrees* for EPSG:4326).

Running

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
       ST_MakeLine(geom ORDER BY "time") AS geom
FROM (
  SELECT "time",
         geom,
         ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, 0.00001, 2) OVER() AS cid
  FROM   <table>
) q
WHERE  cid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
       cid
;
```

should get you close to what you intent; you may need to tweak the `eps` parameter. Setting the `minpts` parameter to 2 marks isolated points with `cid = NULL`, which can then be used to exclude them from creating (invalid) lines.